# Why are these two sparql queries different?

Tags: sparql

```
SELECT ?class (COUNT(?subject) as ?classCount) 
WHERE {
    ?subject ?predicate ?object. 
    ?subject rdf:type ?class .
}
GROUP BY ?class
ORDER BY DESC(?classCount)
```

If I remove '?subject ?predicate ?object.', the query results are different. I understand they should be the same:

```
Finding all triples with a 'rdf:type' relationship. no other conditions.
```

But they produces different results. Why is that?

Comment: why do you think they should be the same? Think of it as each triple pattern being evaluated separately, then joined on the `?subject` variable. Take a sheet of paper with some sample data and see what happens. `SELECT ?class (COUNT(DISTINCT ?subject) as ?classCount)` would  avoid the duplicate `?subject` bindings in your join, so the `DISTINCT` operator is the way to go

Comment: @AKSW, the first says 'find all triples' & the 2nd says 'find all triples with the relationship rdf:type', so the join would be effectively equal to the 2nd alone. However, it isn't the case. Why is that?

Comment: what? why would the join be equal to the second? please, take a small sample and a sheet of paper and do it manually. If you have just `:s rdf:type :C1 . :s rdf:type :C2 . ` you're getting 2 bindings (aka rows) with just the second triple pattern, right? Even this would by the way be not what you want as result (`DISTINCT` operator as I said before is the correct way to go). Now, your first triple pattern also matches both triples, right? So 2 more bindings. Then the join leading to 2 x 2 bindings, right? 4 != 2, so obviously different.

Comment: @AKSW, continue with your example, if the model has two more relationships, :s sings :c3, :s sings :c4. Then the first patterns will return all the 4 triples, and the 2nd only returns the two triples with rdf:type. When they are joined, isn't the result reduced to only the 2nd two triples? Because they not unioned, but joined. Maybe I have some trouble in understanding the semantics of 'join'. Here 'predicate' refers to any relationship, but 'rdf:type' is a subset of any 'predicate'. Right?

Comment: *"When they are joined, isn't the result reduced to only the 2nd two triples?"* - no. I think you misunderstanding join. It's the same like for databases. You have 4 bindings B1 aka rows for the first triple pattern. And you have 2 bindings B2 for the second triple pattern. Then, for each binding in B4 you run through all bindings in B2. It's nothing more than a nested loop. 4 x 2 = 8.

Comment: ?s ?p ?o retrieves any triples from the graph. Why don't these triples include the ?s rdf:type ?o results? rdf:type represents a proper subset of the general relationship ?p. Right? still confused. Even if a superset joins with a subset, the net result is the superset. right?

Comment: still not sure why this is so difficult to understand. the pattern matching generates **all** possible bindings. we also don't have set semantics here. we have partial functions mapping variables to bindings. each triple pattern is evaluated separately, then joined. If you have 4 bindings for the first triple pattern and 2 for the second triple pattern, you'll get 8 final bindings. Again, take a sheet of paper and do it, process triple pattern 1, then process triple pattern 2, then join both results. And again, no set semantics.

Comment: So what do you get as result. Please post the result w.r.t. to the example graph containing the 4 triples `:s rdf:type :C1 . :s rdf:type :C2 . :s sings :c3 , :s sings :c4 .`  here.

Comment: I will leave this for now. Thanks, AKSW.